# Saving only non-null entry value and column number from pandas df with only one non-null value per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with many columns, most of them are null, but for each row there always is one and only one column with value a string.

I am creating a new column in the dataframe that selects the only non-null value:

```
data[label] = data.iloc[:,0]  
for col in range(1,100) :
    data[label] = data[label].fillna(data.iloc[:,col])
```

This works fine, however, I would also keep track of which one of these columns was the non-null, for each entry, so that the column label has that information as well. How do I know which column was non-empty?

```
Ex.

col0      col1     col2
          "red"
"blue"
                  "yellow"

new column label is:

label
"red"/col1
"blue"/col0
"yellow"/col2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert `df` to `True`s where are values by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) and get columns names by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) for values:

```
cols = df.notnull().idxmax(axis=1)
df['a'] = df.lookup(df.index, cols) + '/' + cols
print (df)
   col0 col1    col2            a
0   NaN  red     NaN     red/col1
1  blue  NaN     NaN    blue/col0
2   NaN  NaN  yellow  yellow/col2
```

Another solution with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
cols = df.notnull().idxmax(axis=1)
df['a'] = df.fillna('').sum(axis=1) + '/' + cols
print (df)
   col0 col1    col2            a
0   NaN  red     NaN     red/col1
1  blue  NaN     NaN    blue/col0
2   NaN  NaN  yellow  yellow/col2
```

Another solution, thanks [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590965/saving-only-non-null-entry-value-and-column-number-from-pandas-df-with-only-one/44591134#comment76170098_44591134) - use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html):

```
cols = df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index, axis=1)
df['a'] = df.lookup(cols.index, cols)  + '/' + cols
print (df)
   col0 col1    col2            a
0   NaN  red     NaN     red/col1
1  blue  NaN     NaN    blue/col0
2   NaN  NaN  yellow  yellow/col2
```

Comment: Might get a slight speed up instead of using `idxmax` an dropping non-nulls in using, `cols = df2.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)` and then `df2.lookup(cols, cols.index) + '/' + 'cols.index` - not 100% sure though